# Render data sent to Express post router

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm starting with Express and I have a question; I have the setup and everything, I've made some simple things but know I want to interact with an API, to do what I want to do I need to the data that I want to get it's from an `input` field. I want to refresh the main (`/`) page with the data that was sent. Like a client-side ajax request. I don't know how to send the data that was sent to the post router to the get router without having to go to another link (i.e. localhost:3000/link), i want to stay in the same page where the request was done. I'm using pug (jade) in the template

Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index');
});

/* POST HANDLER */
router.post('/link', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

jQuery:

```
$('#shortLink').on('click', () => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/link',
        data: $('linkInput').val()
    });
});
```

So, to be clear. User puts something on the input field; sends that data to the post router, I want to get the information sent to the post router to be sent to the get router without having to leave the page where the request was done. Let me know if I didn't explain myself very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just say you have the [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) set up and understand how does the templating work.

In this what you want is to somehow save the data somewhere on the server. Now in a very simple case you can just save it to variable:

```
var data = null;
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', { data: null });
});

router.post('/link', function(req, res, next) {
    data = req.body
    res.send('');
});
```

Then in your template you can do `p= data`.

Now after you `post` to the `/link` then on the next refresh `/` will show the data.

In most web applications though, people will save these things to the database. Here's [an example for MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) saving the data to specific document:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    collection.findOne({ id: 'specificDoc'}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.render('index', { data: result.data });
    });
});

router.post('/link', function(req, res, next) {
    collection.update({ id: 'specificDoc', { data: req.data }, { upsert: true }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.send('');
    });
});
```

Probably you might also start using sessions and save the data depending on the user using cookies or other methods. [Here's a toturial](http://expressjs-book.com/index.html%3Fp=128.html) for using sessions in express.

Comment: Hey, it worked but instead of `res.send` I used redirect. Thanks for the input and yes, I'll check out that tutorial,